# Internal Server Error - 500 while making simultaneous AJAX requests in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
function InitializeCharts() {
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     compName = arguments[i];
     $.ajax({
         async:true,
         timeout: 60000,
         dataType: "json",
         url: "/SalesDashboard/GetChartData",
         data: { company: compName, from: startDate, to: endDate },
         success: (function () {
             var cmp = compName;
             return function (data) {
                 ChartData[cmp] = data;
                 PrepareChart(data, cmp);
             };
         })(),
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             console.log(xhr.status+': '+xhr.statusText);                
             console.log(thrownError);
         }
     });
 }
}
```

I'm using the above function at Client Side to make AJAX requests and get some data. It's working fine when I'm calling the function like this:

```
InitializeCharts("ABC"); // A Single parameter
```

It works fine for a single request but when I'm passing multiple parameters like below, it creates multiple simultaneous requests and gives me "**Internal Server Error -500**" Error.

```
InitializeCharts("ABC", "BBC", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "ACD", "CBD", "CDS", "ADB"); // Multiple parameters
```

It gives me the error for few random companies, sometimes for two, sometimes for three or four.
I tried increasing the timeout in AJAX request to 60000 but it didn't work. I also went through IIS Server and increased the connection timeout to 3 minutes but still getting the same response. I know it even doesn't take a single minute to get the data back to the client. If I'm setting the "**async**" value in ajax request to false, it works but blocks the UI until the data returned for all companies.

Below is my Server Side Code:

```
static int hitCount = 0;
private string ConnectionString = "server=localhost;database={0};uid=test;password=test;pooling=false;";

private string QueryString_Daily = "SELECT Day(mergefiledate) AS `Date`, COUNT(order_no) AS `Count` FROM orders_new WHERE DATE(mergefiledate)>='{0}' and Date(mergefiledate)<='{1}' GROUP BY DATE(mergefiledate);";

public Task<string> GetChartData(string company, string from, string to)
    {
        hitCount++;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetData(company, from, to));
    }

private string GetData(string company, string from, string to)
    {            
         string QuerySTR = string.Empty;
         QuerySTR = string.Format(QueryString_Daily, startDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), endDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
         MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(string.Format(ConnectionString, company));
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QuerySTR, mycon);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            mycon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Database connection error, please try again. ERROR_DETAILS: '" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
            return null;
        }

        if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {

            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

        }

        if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                mycon.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
    var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
             return result;
     }
    else
     {
            return null;
         }

    }
```

I've been trying to figure out the solution by Googling, digging on stackoverflow.com ... etc but no luck yet.
Help is highly appreciated, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you make these ajax request synchronously use - async:false

Comment: yes I can and I'm doing this way already, but I'm getting the error while making multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: This is really a server problem. Do you have the backend code? Can you debug it? Does it log errors?

Comment: this looks more like a server-side error... you might want to debug your c# code and look for a problem there. Is there any exception being thrown when making multiple requests simultaneously?

Comment: Looks like some problem with your chart generation code - when you have several requests you have several copies of this code running at the same time. Carefully validate your code for thread-safety.

Comment: You are doing **async:true** I suggested **async:false**. It does look like a server problem though. Another problem (not related to the problem you posted) with the above code is the small semi-colon after **async:true**

Comment: @Chips_100: Sir, I've updated my server-side code in question. Can you please check and suggest me what modifications I need to check or to ensure for thread-safety. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Pavel_Kutakov: Sir, I've updated my server-side code in question. Can you please check and suggest me what modifications I need to check or to ensure for thread-safety. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please start the application in debug mode, that way Visual Studio will break and show you exactly the type and location of any exception. Also, we will need the actual content of `GetData`. It is impossible to find the problem with neither complete code nor an exception message.

Comment: @Wutz I've updated the code for server side method. I've tried to catch if any exception is being thrown but it all works fine, PS.

Comment: Did you chekeout the amount of simultaneos connections to the MySql? Looks like timeout from the DB when you queue lots of request. Did you check the MySql log? Any lockout?

Comment: @Fals: yes I did. I think if all the tables are different for each request, tables can't get locked out, please correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone for putting efforts. I got the solution. i was in the impression that I've set the command timeout for infinite by using the statement below but actually I was wrong:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

I modified the timeout as :

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

and it worked perfectly. Thanks again for every little help.

Comment: I knew that! MySQL timeouts sucks! :)